# How to have a longer xterm title in zsh

Tags: debian, terminal, zsh, window-title

I am using zsh 5.3 . I saw https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#xterm_title and decided to use it -

```
~/.zshrc

autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

function xterm_title_precmd () {
    print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m %1~\a'
}

function xterm_title_preexec () {
    print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m %1~ %# '
    print -n "${(q)1}\a"
}

if [[ "$TERM" == (screen*|xterm*|rxvt*) ]]; then
    add-zsh-hook -Uz precmd xterm_title_precmd
    add-zsh-hook -Uz preexec xterm_title_preexec
fi
```

while it works and worked beautifully, it didn't do it wholly. For instance it shows -

```
shirish@think-debian prompts
```

instead of

```
shirish@thnk-debian /usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts
```

which would be the full path. While I do understand that is beneficial esp. if you are on a laptop or some smaller screen-sized device, on desktops this should show the full path.

Does anybody know how I can do this ?

I do know that what needs to be changed is in  within the Print but what ?

```
function xterm_title_precmd () {
        print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m %1~\a'
    }

    function xterm_title_preexec () {
        print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m %1~ %# '
        print -n "${(q)1}\a"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) `%~` is expanded to the directory name, but using `~` in place of `$HOME`. `%1~` says just to use the last 1 component of the name.

So just remove the `1` in `'\e]2;%n@%m %1~\a'`