# how to show more entries than the default 16 in zsh?

Tags: debian, zsh, command-history

This is my ~/.zsh/.zshrc -

```
/home/shirish/.zsh> cat .zshrc
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.zsh//.histfile
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=100000
setopt inc_append_history autocd nomatch notify share_history
bindkey -e
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install

# display how long all tasks over 10 seconds take
export REPORTTIME=10

# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/shirish/.zsh//.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit promptinit
compinit
promptinit
# End of lines added by compinstall

#from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332732/removing-strange-characters-from-a-zsh-prompt

export LC_ALL=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_IN.UTF-8

#from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332888/how-to-have-a-longer-xterm-title-in-zsh

autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

function xterm_title_precmd () {
    print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m %1~\a'
}

function xterm_title_preexec () {
    print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m %~ %# '
    print -n "${(q)1}\a"
}

if [[ "$TERM" == (screen*|xterm*|rxvt*) ]]; then
    add-zsh-hook -Uz precmd xterm_title_precmd
    add-zsh-hook -Uz preexec xterm_title_preexec
fi


prompt bigfade
```

Now if I try to get history output I get only 16 entries in history from .zsh. What if I want to see all the entries. For some reason it saves/shows only 16, the rest either seem not to be recorded  I do have multiple tabs of the same shell. I dunno if it's a bug or something more that I need to add.

Comment: Try `history -17`.

Comment: but I want to stretch history to couple of hundred entries or so, not like what has been shared.

Comment: also updated my question to better reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

From `man fc`:

> If  first  and last are both omitted, the previous 16 commands shall be listed or the previous single command shall be edited (based on the −l option).

To solve your issue: `alias history='fc -l -100'`

Comment: Minor issue:  `man fc` shows doc about bash builtins, which includes fc. To show zsh doc on fc, we need to use `man zshbuiltins`.