# zsh: How to increase the default number of history entries displayed?

Tags: zsh, command-history

When I run the `history` command I only get 16 lines of output:

```
$ history | wc -l
16
```

Is there an environment variable that I can set within my `.zshrc` file or some other way to increase the number of history entries that are displayed by default?

My primary reason for wanting to do this is because I often search for previous commands using

`history | grep something`

but now that I've switched from bash to zsh I get only 16 lines of history output (it seems that the default number on bash is 1000) so now I need to also specify the number of entries that are returned:

`history -2000 | grep something`

Is there a way to set the default number of entries that `history` displays? (Or maybe I'm searching `history` wrong and should learn a better way to find a previous command?)

BTW I am using zsh on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Same: https://superuser.com/q/160342/736190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is already answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417156/34505).

Here is a direct copy-paste of that answer:

> From man fc:
>
> ```
> If first and last are both omitted, the previous 16 commands shall be listed or the previous single command shall be edited (based on the −l option).
> ```
>
> To solve your issue: alias history='fc -l -100'

To add on to this answer, personally I use `alias histsearch='fc -l 0 | grep'` to search all of my history.

Comment: Thanks for this and for pointing out the previously answered question. I guess since it only mentions "entries" and not "history" entries in the title I missed it in my initial search. Can we somehow edit that question's title to include "history"? My reputation here isn't sufficient to edit (although it's over 3500 on StackOverflow), otherwise, I'd try to fix that myself. In any event thanks again for your help!

Comment: To me - that looks like a workaround and not a solution. Where does one configure the behaviour of the original 'history' command?

Comment: @user176181 `history` isn't really its own command; it is an alias for `fc -l`.  So re-aliasing `history` to `fc -l -100` is literally "changing the behavior of the original history command".